# Customizing "next" and "previous" arrow in Carousel of Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new beginner of Twitter Bootstrap. I tried to place a Carousel lightbox at the center of my page. I edited css to do so. However, I found no where to edit the location of "next" and "previous" arrow.

Here's my page.
http://www.nienyiho.com/portfolio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to edit it using the CSS (I assume you do) then it can be found on lines 54 and 74 of bootstrap-carousel.css

Answer (score 7):

Here are some relevant sections from the bootstrap.css file in case you can't find it on exactly 54 and 74

```css
.carousel-control .glyphicon,
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  font-family: serif;
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev:before {
  content: '\2039';
}

.carousel-control .icon-next:before {
  content: '\203a';
}
```